# Error when connecting Rosbridge (Web Sockets)

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, websocket, ros

I am developing an app for iOS with Swift 3, this application search with the Bonjour service some robots in the local network which use a specific service, for example **robot.local** and show them in a list. The Bonjour service gives me the domain of the device. This is a example of the domains searched.

Ex.:

- robot1.local
- robot2.local

The next step, is when the user click an element of the list. This action start a connection by web sockets with the device and connect it for control it with the Iphone. I am using a library called [RBManager](https://github.com/wesgood/RBManager) which use [RocketSocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket) library for connect. This library helps me to connect to RosBridge.

I use this code for connect:

```
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://192.168.0.100:9090"]];
self.socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:request];
self.socket.delegate = self;
[self.socket open];
```

The problem is when I am install the app by Xcode I have not any problem but when I am install the app by an **ipa** file or by TestFlight the connection is rejected and shows this error:

> managerDidFailWithError Optional(ErrorDomain=NSOSTatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-9807 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807})

I found this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket/issues/467) in the library but is not the solution that I need.

I am deactive ATS in the info.plist but I not know how to solve this error. Could anyone help me?

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was that my RosBridge backend run with TLS and I didn't implement it.

The solution is implement the authentication in the client and all works :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.